# How to get the minimum id from the table in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a MySql query to get the columns related with minimum id . Looks something like this

```
SELECT min(id) as ID,feed , idpropiedad FROM `registrofeed` WHERE feed=21
```

The table has 4 rows looks like this

[image]

So according to the function that I have written

```
function setLC()
 {
    
     $sql = "
SELECT min(id) as ID
  , feed 
  , idpropiedad 
  FROM `registrofeed` 
 WHERE feed=21
";
     $result = $this->localDb->execute($sql);
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo $sql;
     echo $row['idpropiedad'];
     $this->lastCode = $row['idpropiedad'];
 }
```

It returns empty string for idpropiedad

Can any one help me out where I am going wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've asked MySQL to return an idpropriedad of its choice. So it does.

Comment: order by ascending get the first row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd think the query you're actually looking for is this:

```
SELECT id, feed, idpropiedad 
  FROM registrofeed 
 WHERE feed = 21 
 ORDER BY id ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

`MIN()` is giving you the generally lowest value in the column, it does not affect the rest of the columns. If you want the whole *row* with the lowest `id` it doesn't help.

To illustrate, if you really wanted to use `MIN` here, you'd have to do:

```
SELECT id, feed, idpropiedad 
  FROM registrofeed 
 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM registrofeed WHERE feed = 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a better query like this:

```
 $sql = "
SELECT id as ID
  , feed 
  , idpropiedad 
  FROM `registrofeed` 
 WHERE feed=21
 HAVING MIN(id)
";
```

This will return only one row with the minimum id number. It's more readable than using ORDERING AND LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

try your select query as

SELECT * FROM `registrofeed` WHERE `feed`='21' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1

this fetches the row having minimum id.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT min(id) as ID,feed , idpropiedad FROM `registrofeed` WHERE feed='21' order by id  asc";
```